# LINQ Select child records error "The query contains a projection"

Tags: c#, linq

I have my Data Models SalesOrder / SalesOrderItem

I have two view models SalesOrderReport / SalesOrderItemReport

I select my sales order and populate my view model.

The problem occurs when I try to load the child objects in the same statement:

```
var salesOrderReport =
        from o in _context.SalesOrder
            .Include(p => p.SalesOrderItems)
            .Include(p => p.Customer)
            .Include(p => p.Tax)
            .Include(p => p.Currency)
        where o.SalesOrderId == salesOrderId
        select new SalesOrderReport
        {
            SalesOrderId = o.SalesOrderId,
            OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber,
            OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
            
            SalesOrderItemReports = from i in _context.SalesOrderItem
                              .Include(p => p.Product)
                              .Include(p => p.ProductVariation)
                              .Where(p => p.SalesOrderId == o.SalesOrderId) select new SalesOrderItemReport
            {
                SalesOrderItemId = i.SalesOrderItemId,
                SalesOrderId = i.SalesOrderId,
                Qty = i.Qty,
                UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice,
                InternalSku = i.Product == null ? null : i.ProductVariation == null ? i.Product.InternalSku : i.ProductVariation.InternalSku,
            }
        };
```

When I remove the item select, the statement executes correctly and returns my SalesOrderReport.

I have never seen the error "The query contains a projection" and there seems to be little information about it.

Comment: The error is referring to the embedded select. This is not allowed. You need to find another way, which is usually a join.

Comment: Of course you are both correct. I have only just started working with LINQ. I managed to get around the issue by including the required items / products / variations in the initial _context select.

Comment: There are ways around this, maybe you can use a join or navigation property

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query without `Include` - it is not needed in custom projection and not allowed in projection body.

```cs
var salesOrderReport =
    from o in _context.SalesOrder
    where o.SalesOrderId == salesOrderId
    select new SalesOrderReport
    {
        SalesOrderId = o.SalesOrderId,
        OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber,
        OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
        
        SalesOrderItemReports = o.SalesOrderItems
            .Select(i => new SalesOrderItemReport
            {
                SalesOrderItemId = i.SalesOrderItemId,
                SalesOrderId = i.SalesOrderId,
                Qty = i.Qty,
                UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice,
                InternalSku = i.Product.InternalSku ?? i.ProductVariation.InternalSku,
            }).ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Thank you Syvataslav. I was just searching for why using my include statements fetched all columns from the DB and not just the ones I wanted to select.

Comment: Unfortunately this still gives the same error: "System.InvalidOperationException: The query contains a projection". I had to add "new" before "SalesOrderItemReport" for this code to work.

Comment: @steve_c123, missed new keyword. It is a problem?

Comment: I had to change it to SalesOrderItems = o.SalesOrderItems.Select( and drop the _context which was causing the error. However, on looking at Profiler, all of the columns for Product are being fetched and not just the ones I wanted (qty / UnitPrice / SKU).

Comment: Which type has column `InternalSku`? It is nullable type?

Comment: InternalSku exists on both Product and ProductVariation. The code works fine but there are a lot of columns in Product / Productvariation which are being fetched.

Comment: I'm asking because want to correct query. I need their types.

Comment: Sorry, Syvatoslav. It is a string public string ManufacturerSku { get; set; }

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the projection error System.InvalidOperationException: The query contains a projection 'o => DbSet<SalesOrderItem>

Comment: Added `ToList()` call. It is last chance. This query is not complex and should work.

Comment: Also, does `SalesOrder` has navigation property `OrderItems`?

Comment: ToList() works but it pulls the entire Product / Variation table columns in the query.  I might have to try Dapper for this which is a shame. SalesOrder has SalesOrderItem navigation property, yes. I had to use o.SalesOrderItems instead of _context.SalesOrderItem.Where...

Comment: @steve_c123, updated with using navigation property. It is more intuitive way.

Comment: Yes please see comment above. Works but using profiler, I can see it selects the entire Product / ProductVariation column set which is not feasible.

Comment: @steve_c123, update to the latest EF Core, or do not use at all )). It is not single bug in this library.

Comment: I've just switched to Dapper. It's a lot easier to write my own SQL and a lot more elegant!  Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: So, maybe better to switch to `linq2db`. Dapper is step back from usability,

Comment: In what way, Svyatoslav? I cannot see anything being easier than creating my SQL query and populating my DTO model from it in a few lines of code. Happy to look at linq2db if it offers anything above this.

Comment: LINQ gives ability to reuse code, filters, subqueries. For me it is easier to write LINQ query, because i’m good in that. Also like a Dapper  linq2db provides various ways to execute SQL and map results to DTO.

Comment: Some queries like the one above ends up being a complete mess in LINQ / EF. I will be sure to give linq2db a look. Thank you